# how do i create a scroll box and then add things to it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game and i want to create a scrollbox with html, and then add things to it later with javascript, further on in the same code. Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example done with Javascript, you should be able to go from there, though I would recommend doing this with jQuery instead, since manipulating DOM objects will be much easier.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9Tys/

CSS (for scrollbox):

```
#scrollbox {
overflow: scroll;
width: 600px;
height: 100px;
}
```

A scrollbox and link to add new elements:

```
<div id="scrollbox">
</div>
<a onclick="addElement()">Add element</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function addElement() {
    var scrollbox = document.getElementById('scrollbox');

    // Create some element, e.g. div
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.setAttribute('id', "some-id-for-new-element");
    newElement.innerHTML = 'New element has been added!';

    scrollbox.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. you should use div them make it overflow

> div
>
> {
>
> > width:150px;
> >
> > height:150px;
> >
> > word-wrap:break-word;
> >
> > overflow:scroll;
>
> }

something like that.

then use javascript and append() event

Comment: i don't know how to create an append() event, can you give an example?

Comment: @Yajo100 an example would be `$('#foo').append('bar');`

Comment: $('#div_id').append('text_you_will_append');